# how to access @private variable _navigationBar in the UINavigationItem class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, private, uinavigationitem

`UINavigationItem` has the following private variables

```
UIKIT_EXTERN_CLASS @interface UINavigationItem : NSObject <NSCoding> {

@private
 NSString        *_title;
 NSString        *_backButtonTitle;
 UIBarButtonItem *_backBarButtonItem;
 NSString        *_prompt;
 NSInteger        _tag;
 id               _context;
 UINavigationBar *_navigationBar;
 UIView          *_defaultTitleView;
 UIView          *_titleView;
 UIView          *_backButtonView;
 UIBarButtonItem *_leftBarButtonItem;
 UIBarButtonItem *_rightBarButtonItem;
 UIView          *_customLeftView;
 UIView          *_customRightView;
 BOOL             _hidesBackButton;
 UIImageView     *_frozenTitleView;

}
```

Is there any way (using KVC,etc.) to read the `UINavigationBar *_navigationBar;`
I need this to get access to the undefined backButton. which is not in:

`@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem;`
`@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Don't do this.*** It violates the fundamental OOP concept of encapsulation. If Apple decides to rearrange the order or meaning of the ivars in the `UINavigationItem` class, your code may break unpredictably up to and including crashes or man-eating purple dragons.

---

That said, if you're sure you want to go down this **evil** ***evil*** road, you should be able to reach the `_navigationBar` ivar with:

```
UINavigationItem *theItem = ...;
UINavigationBar *bar = [theItem valueForKey: @"_navigationBar"];
```

If that doesn't work (for instance, if Apple has overridden `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` on this class), you can drop down to the Objective-C runtime:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

UINavigationItem *theItem = ...;
UINavigationBar *bar = nil;
Ivar barIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([UINavigationItem class], "_navigationItem");
if (barIvar) {
    bar = *(UINavigationBar *)((void *)theItem + ivar_getOffset(barIvar));
}
```

Both approaches are incredibly dangerous and run the risk of breaking with any and every point release of the operating system. ***You have been warned. Here be dragons.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the navigationBar on the UINavigationController, not the UINavigationItem

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd access the navigationBar on UINavigationController like Christian said.

If you must access the navigationBar through the UINavigationItem, creating a custom subclass of UINavigationItem, then a custom variable is an alternative.

Lastly, if you really don't care too much about any of the alternatives and really, really want to access that property, then you'd simply call:

```
[myNavigationItem performSelector:@selector(navigationBar)]
```

Of course the usual, "will get your app rejected" or "it's not good coding" statements apply.